# Why is $\Delta ABC\sim \Delta AEC\sim \Delta FBC$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Why is $\Delta ABC\sim \Delta AEC\sim \Delta FBC$?  I see that they have two angles in common and also share a side. But this doesn't make them similar as far as I am concerned.[image]

Rectangles of the same color are equal in area, angles of the same color are equal in size.

Comment: If two triangles have two angles respectively congruent, then they are similar.

Comment: Isn't there extra information?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Does anyone know why $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{r}{a}$ holds?

Comment: @Analysis: that follows from the similarity, ratio of corresponding sides is the same.

Comment: @Vasili Yes, but I would think it is $a/c=a/r$.

Comment: @Analysis: No, in $\triangle ABC$, $c$ is opposite of $\angle C$, in $\triangle ACE$, $a$ is opposite of $\angle AEC=\angle C$. Hence $\frac{r}{a}$. Note that $\angle ACE=\angle B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider triangles $ABC$ and $ACE$. They have $\angle A$ in common and $\angle ACB=\angle AEC$ by construction. Hence they are similar.

An analogous reasoning can be made to show that $ABC\sim FCB$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a stupid mistake by thinking that two angles of the same size does not imply similiarty. But if we know about two angles, we know about the thrid since their sum is 180. What I still don't understand is why from this similarity one gets $a^2=rc$ or $b^2=sc$. Do you by any chance know this too?

Comment: Do you know why $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{r}{a}$ holds?

Comment: @Analysis As Vasili commented above, sides with the same ratio are opposite to equal angles. Hence $AC/AE=BC/CE=AB/AC$. And $AC/AE=AB/AC$ can be rewritten as $AC/AB=AE/AC$.